# Catching abort()

Tags: c#, wpf, com, abort

I'm referencing a c++ COM library in a WPF application whose code has unfortunately been lost. I'm pretty sure the library is calling abort() or doing something that's causing the process to die. Is there a way to catch something like this so I can log and/or troubleshoot?

Edit: The specific error I'm getting is:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Then the process quits.

Comment: Try DispatcherUnhandledException  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743714%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Unhandled_Exceptions

Comment: are you able to attach a debugger?

Comment: I can attach a debugger to the c# application, but I don't see any exception, the process just dies. I'm not very familiar with c++ so I'm not sure how to attach to the library if that's what you meant.

Comment: If the process is just dying, that's likely a stack overflow.

Comment: @PeterRitchie It could be an intentional attempt to bring down the proccess.  A managed equivalent would be something like `Environment.FailFast`.

Comment: FailFast/abort invokes code to exit the application.  Certain stack overflows cause the OS to simply unload the application with no warning.

Comment: @RandomParentheses Do you see entries in the debugger output like "thread xxx exited" when the application exits?  Or, does Visual Studio simply transition from (Running) to not running without any output?

Comment: Okay, with the error information just added, it's definitely not a stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

If you're referencing a library that is (intentionally or not) bringing down the entire process, your first goal should obviously be to avoid the situation.  Look for patches, alternative references, fix the reference (if that's possible), etc.  Consider the possibility that the library is being fed bad data, or if there is in some other way to avoid having it crash in the first place through proper use of said library.  This is a bad position to be in, and may well be a sign that even if you could recover from this, your program is very likely to be in a state in which you wouldn't *want* to.

Your best bet when working with a library such as this, assuming you have no choice in the matter, is to run it in an *entirely separate process*.  Spin up a worker process and use some form of inter process communication to have it send back the results of whatever you're having the library do.  This way the library will only ever take down this worker process, and you can be at least moderately safe in terms of knowing that your main process is in a state in which continuing on is a valid option.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I'm trying to "catch" the abort more to troubleshoot what's happening, not to continue.

Answer (score 1):

To "catch" the abort, you can outright put a breakpoint in `abort()`, I think. Have your initialization code reference it in some way (function pointer, etc.) to get its address, then jump to this address on the disassembly window to put a breakpoint there.